# json_decode выдает NULL, где ошибка?

Tags: json, php

Есть переменная такого плана:

```
$a = '{"_text": "москв", "_item_list": [{"_text": "<u>Москв</u>а", "_plain_text": "Москва", "_is_international": "1"}, {"_text": "<u>Москв</u>орецкая", "_plain_text": "Москворецкая", "_is_international": "1"}, {"_text": "<u>Москв</u>оречье", "_plain_text": "Москворечье", "_is_international": "1"}]}';
```

json_decode($a) выдает NULL.

где ошибка?

Comment: [json_last_error()][1] показывает код ошибки 5 или JSON_ERROR_UTF8. Значит, ошибка где-то в кодировке.

[1]:http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

отлично всё отработало. проверьте установлен ли модуль json на сервере.

**Дополнено:**

```
function json_encode_utf($value) 
    {
        if (is_int($value)) {
            return (string)$value;   
        } elseif (is_string($value)) {
            $value = str_replace(array('\\', '/', '"', "\r", "\n", "\b", "\f", "\t"), 
                                 array('\\\\', '\/', '\"', '\r', '\n', '\b', '\f', '\t'), $value);
            $convmap = array(0x80, 0xFFFF, 0, 0xFFFF);
            $result = "";
            for ($i = mb_strlen($value) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
                $mb_char = mb_substr($value, $i, 1);
                if (mb_ereg("&#(\\d+);", mb_encode_numericentity($mb_char, $convmap, "UTF-8"), $match)) {
                    $result = sprintf("\\u%04x", $match[1]) . $result;
                } else {
                    $result = $mb_char . $result;
                }
            }
            return '"' . $result . '"';                
        } elseif (is_float($value)) {
            return str_replace(",", ".", $value);         
        } elseif (is_null($value)) {
            return 'null';
        } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
            return $value ? 'true' : 'false';
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $with_keys = false;
            $n = count($value);
            for ($i = 0, reset($value); $i < $n; $i++, next($value)) {
                        if (key($value) !== $i) {
                  $with_keys = true;
                  break;
                        }
            }
        } elseif (is_object($value)) {
            $with_keys = true;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
        $result = array();
        if ($with_keys) {
            foreach ($value as $key => $v) {
                $result[] = json_encode_utf((string)$key) . ':' . F::json_encode($v);    
            }
            return '{' . implode(',', $result) . '}';                
        } else {
            foreach ($value as $key => $v) {
                $result[] = json_encode_utf($v);    
            }
            return '[' . implode(',', $result) . ']';
        }
    }
```

Comment: сделал json_last_error()...выдало ошибку "5", решил проблему сменой кодировки перед json_decode...но не уверен что это правильно. Неужели json_decode не может работать с UTF8?

Comment: к сожалению пока не может. дополнил ответ где то увидел функцию, написано конечно коряво, но работает.

Answer (score 0):

Проверить `JSON` на валидность можно по [**этой ссылке**](http://json.parser.online.fr/).

**UPD:** Вставил ваш код в файл, преобразовал файл в кодировку **UTF-8 без BOM** в редакторе [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) - всё заработало.